# Read Objects from file - vanishing References

Tags: java

I'm trying do something like that:

Person; PersonList (ArrayList) contains Person;

Summary contains PersonList;

SummaryList (ArrayList) contains Summary.

Next I want to modify my Person and save it to file, like in code below:

```
//first run
    personList.addPerson(); // PersonArrayList: [Person: Anonymous Person]

    summaryList.addSummary(personList); // SummaryArrayList: [Summary: Test,  PersonArrayList: [Person: Anonymous Person]]

    modifyPerson(personList); // set lastName to ModifiedPerson
    // PersonArrayList: [Person: Anonymous ModifiedPerson]
    // SummaryArrayList: [Summary: Test,  PersonArrayList: [Person: Anonymous ModifiedPerson]]

    save.savePersonListToDatabase(personList);
    save.saveSummaryToDatabase(summaryList);
/*
here is OK. Is one instance of PersonList and one instance of Person. Change in Person affect to both Lists.
end of first run
*/
```

Next I want to read it from file. I use this code to read from file (and similar to save):

```
public Object readObjectFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println("Read " + filePath + " is OK");
    objectInputStream.close();
    return object;
}

public PersonList readPersonListFromDatabase() {
    try{
        String personFilePath = "PersonList.obj";
        personList = (PersonList) readObjectFromFile(personFilePath);
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return personList;
}
```

and second run:

```
//second run
    personList = read.readPersonListFromDatabase();
    summaryList = read.readSummaryListFromDatabase();
/*
here is NOT ok. There are two instances of PersonList and two instances of Person. Change in Person does
not affect on SummaryList (because there are different instances of it)
*/
```

I use `Serializable` and `FileOutputStream` / `ObjectOutputStream` to save it.

I want to run program, do my things, save it all and close. In next run I want to read it all from files.

What should I do, if I want to keep all references after read from file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

Follow to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374665/14558334

I create a "container" class which looks like that:

```
public class ClassContainer implements Serializable {
    private SummaryList summaryList;
    private PersonList personList;

    public ClassContainer(SummaryList summaryList, PersonList personList) {
        this.summaryList = summaryList;
        this.personList = personList;
    }
}
```

Thanks to this I save / read only one object with every references saved.

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it works fine.